# A strange issue in Android O about typing using soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I tried my app in Android O and came up with a strange issue. I have a RecipientEditTextView which extends the AutoCompeteTextView, and after mismatch happens, the focus is still on the textview and cursor still flashing, however, the bottom buttons are pushed down and soft keyboard is still shown, when you try to type the soft keyboard, you just interact with the components beneath the keyboard. Since the code is quite complex I really cannot post code here. So my question is when can a soft keyboard be shown while cannot be typed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long standing bug.  Keyboards are bound to views.  You can get into a situation where the keyboard is bound to the wrong view.  In that case, the typing will go to the view its bound to, and not to the one you expect.  This is especially likely after a crash, you may see DeadObjectExceptions in the log.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation to fix this issue? And do you know why before Oreo it was OK and now the bug pop up?

Comment: I tried to add a listener to the popupwindow dismiss event, and the listener will call the method that requestFocus() and show soft keyboard, but turns out useless since it happens after this in looper...Thank you for the knowledge.